# Datadog causing error "npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded" during azure pipeline cmdline step

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, datadog

I have a React app with datadog installed that builds and runs locally just fine

But when I deploy this app with my Azure pipeline I get the following error:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\eca2c149-f450-4d3c-b1a8-353f14f2790c.cmd""
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-03-17T14_29_20_061Z-debug.log
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: CmdLine
```

[image]

Anyone have any ideas about what is causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hello there, please check whether my answer below can help you. If not, could you please provide more detailed information? Is there anything interesting in the logs provided in the error message? What commands are this task executing? Also, you can set [System.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) to true to get detailed debug log.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the command `npm install` and your project has a `node_modules` folder, please try deleting the folder and run your pipeline again.